# conda won't update on MacOS

Tags: macos, conda

I am currently on conda version 4.12.0 and am trying to update it to the latest version (version 23.3.1)

I'm using a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) running on macOS Ventura 13.3.1.

Common comands used for updating conda, won't update conda on my MacBook. I restarted by MacBook multiple times, but this did not resolve the issue.

I tried three commands for updating, but always the same response appears. These are the three commands I used in the terminal (in the base environment):

1. `(base) henrilila@Henris-MacBook-Pro-2020 ~ % conda update --all`
2. `(base) henrilila@Henris-MacBook-Pro-2020 ~ % conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
3. `(base) henrilila@Henris-MacBook-Pro-2020 ~ % Conda update conda`

This is the responds I get, when using the commands above:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.12.0
  latest version: 23.3.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Something must be conflicting with upgrading. You can be more specific with something like: `conda install -n base -c defaults 'conda>=23.3.1'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proposed by @merv, specifying the version to which I want to update solved the issue.

```bash
conda install -n base -c defaults 'conda>=23.3.1'
```